# Is it possible to have Where or Any expression inside Include in Linq or Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Something similar to this

Ex

```
var temp = dbcontext.ModelA.include(x=>x.ModelB.where(...))
var temp = dbcontext.ModelA.include(x=>x.ModelB.Any(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes [filtered includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) are supported, but only as of EF Core 5.0, which would allow you to use `Where`.

According to the docs:

> Supported operations are: `Where`, `OrderBy`, `OrderByDescending`, `ThenBy`, `ThenByDescending`, `Skip`, and `Take`.

However, using `Any` directly does not make sense, because it returns `bool` rather than a subset of related entities.